# Cognitive Architectures: how do you perform qualitative and quantitative comparisons?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I couldn't find a sub stackexchange for artificial intelligence, but I think robotics comes close, and so I'm posting here.

I recently saw TED talks on [AI](https://www.ted.com/topics/ai) and the Google car, with these being the most interesting to me:

1. [Hod Lipson - Building "self-aware" robots](https://www.ted.com/talks/hod_lipson_builds_self_aware_robots)
2. [Juan Enriquez - The next species of human](https://www.ted.com/talks/juan_enriquez_shares_mindboggling_new_science?language=en)
3. [Ray Kurzweil - Get ready for hybrid thinking](https://www.ted.com/talks/ray_kurzweil_get_ready_for_hybrid_thinking)

The third one led me to the ['criticism' section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Create_a_Mind#Analysis) (labeled `Analysis` on that wiki article, though it certainly at least partially reads as a criticism section as well) of Kurzweil 'theory' of the brain, namely ["Pattern Recognition Theory of Mind" (PRTM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Create_a_Mind#Pattern_Recognition_Theory_of_Mind).  After some link surfing on the people who have performed analysis of PRTM and their respective academic contributions, I came to learn about [Cognitive Architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_architecture):

> "A cognitive architecture can refer to a theory about the structure of
>   the human mind. One of the main goals of a cognitive architecture is
>   to summarize the various results of cognitive psychology in a
>   comprehensive computer model. However, the results need to be in a
>   formalized form so far that they can be the basis of a computer
>   program. By combining the individual results are so for a
>   comprehensive theory of cognition and the other a commercially usable
>   model arise. Successful cognitive architectures include ACT-R
>   (Adaptive Control of Thought, ACT), SOAR and OpenCog."

It appears that there are several interesting architectures, including the 3 mentioned above.  I read a bit about [ACT-R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACT-R), [SOAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soar_(cognitive_architecture)), [OpenCog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCog), [DUAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DUAL_(cognitive_architecture)), [CHREST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHREST), and [CLARION](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLARION_(cognitive_architecture)).  The list is not comprehensive.  It also appears that there are two main types of such architectures: [Connectionism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectionism) and [Symbolic](http://ai.eecs.umich.edu/cogarch2/prop/symbolism.html).

Though I have many questions, my main question is this:
**What are some quantitative metrics and qualitative properties to measure and compare between the two architecture types?**

Other questions

- Can all architectures be categorized as one, the other, or some
  combination of the two, or is there a third, fourth, etc?
- How are two main types alike? How are they different?
- What are some recommended further readings on this topic.
- What centres and organizations are leading development in this?
- What are some of the computer programming languages, related skill-sets, and
  cross-domain knowledge set utilized in R&D and product offerings of
  such systems?

Comment: **First**, OP stands for "Original Poster" - the person that asked the question. This is you. **Second**, questions that should be asked here are questions that are closed-ended, in that they should have 1 correct answer. The only question you have asked that meets this criteria is 1.3 - Is there a way to benchmark architecture types. I would ask that you edit your question to only ask that one, and take all of the other questions to [the Robotics chat room.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6221/asimovs-corner)

Comment: Welcome to *robotics* Saad Shakil, but I'm afraid that open ended questions like this really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: I've asked the question that meets the criteria in a less open-ended manner.  Does it qualify to be taken off hold now? I believe it does 'inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”', it will likely 'tend to have long, not short, answer', I certainly think it has a 'constructive, fair, and impartial tone', I look fwd to knowing 'experiences over opinions', certainly all of it 'backed up with facts and references', and certainly 'more than just mindless social fun'.

Comment: I still feel that it is too broad, as it probably falls under the category of needing a book to fully explain, but I'll reopen it as an experiment, to see if anyone can have a go at answering it.

Comment: There are more than two architecture types. Are you looking for benchmarking *any* two architecture types, or are you looking to compare approaches? You linked to connectionism, can you link to symbolic as well?

Comment: BTW - there now *is* a separate AI stack exchange: http://ai.stackexchange.com/

Comment: May want to post it to the AI stackexchange - ai.stackexchange.com